# Configuring HAProxy to route traffic based on url_param

Tags: apache, load-balancing, haproxy

I am very new to HAProxy. I spent a few hours trying to figure out how to do it but could not get any leads. My requirement is this:

If end point of request is /special then I need to check URL_PARAM.

> For example: localhost/special?id=10

Based on ID, I need to route it to one of the 3 servers. `If id <=3 server1, if id > 3 and id <=6 server2 else server3`.

If end point is not /special round robin between all 3 servers.

How do I achieve this 2 level balancing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`urlp`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#urlp) and `urlp_val` to extract the id. Then, use acl to [match the integer](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/snapshot/configuration.html#7.1.2):

```
acl is_special     path_beg /special
acl small_id         urlp_val(id) le 3
acl medium_id        urlp_val(id) 4:6
acl high_id          urlp_val(id) gt 6

use_backend bck1     if is_special small_id
use_backend bck2     if is_special medium_id
use_backend bck3     if is_special high_id
default_backend      bck_all
```

Then, create 3 backends: one for each case.

Edit:

If you want to use regex on the query param, use `urlp_reg`:

```
acl small_id       urlp_reg(id) ^[0-3]
acl medium_id      urlp_reg(id) ^[4-6]
acl high_id        urlp_reg(id) ^[7-9]
```

Also check [`stick`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#stick), depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if integer ID is really big. If it can only be considered as string. Apologies for not making it clear in the example. Can I use some sort of regex range match on it?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized from my data sample that the IDs are from basically UIDs.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the comparison support 64 bit numbers? I have a range like "456304162255302657" to "456316501914435584" and so on and this doesn't seem to be able to compare them. This does work for smaller numbers though.